# How can I merge the fields from different HashMaps into one?

Tags: struct, types, rust

I have the following struct:

```
pub struct Resource {
    name: String,
    info: HashMap<String, i32>,
    info_float: HashMap<String, f32>,
    info_string: HashMap<String, String>,
}
```

Is there a way to merge the 3 `HashMap`s with separate values into a single `HashMap`?

Comment: I don't think you've made it clear enough what you mean by merge. What if the keys collide? Does each key exist in all three, or just one at a time?

Comment: That not clear please precise what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a tuple:

```
pub struct Resource {
    name: String,
    info: HashMap<String, (i32, f32, String)>,
}
```

See it in action at the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=ccb71c53e061ada9570ab0fa433a2a82).

Comment: or a structure.

Comment: or an enum if each key can only have a single type, or a tuple of `Option`s if some keys may be missing

Comment: I'll put more effort into the answer as soon as the op make the question more clear.